# how to make iCarousel items sorting order fixed?

Tags: ios, icarousel

I'm using iCarousel to scroll between images with type "iCarouselTypeTimeMachine". but it has this ugly effect.
The images come in front of each other only when the scrolling ends, briefly views sorting order is not fixed! which caused a lot of other problems.

Comment: Here are some examples of iCarousel. Maybe it can help you. https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel

Comment: What exactly do you want to accomplish? Do you want to remove the fade effect occurs when you scroll??

Comment: i don't wanna remove anything except this effect ...
when i add more than 5 items in the carousel and scroll between them     items sorting order is changing .. Ex: if i put item as the 1st in the carousel after scroll, this item may be number 4 or whatever .. i don't know what causes this effect, i just need any suggestions from where to start?